# ServiceStack X-HTTP-Method-Override

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I have a ServiceStack web service that requires support for the X-HTTP-Method-Override header.

I tried simulating the **Delete request** to through a **Get request** with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header set but I get a:-

```
404 - Handler for Request not found
```

Here's what the request format:

```
Get - http://localhost/test/1
```

***Headers***

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
X-HTTP-Method-Override: Delete
```

And the Service and its DTO implementation looks like:

```
[Route("/test/{id}", HttpMethods.Delete)]
public class TestRequest {
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class TestService : Service {

    public object Delete(TestRequest request){
        return request.id;
    }
}
```

I found a [snippet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Extensions/HttpRequestWrapper.cs#L64) in the ServiceStack source that says X-HTTP-Method-Override feature is supported.

Is there something else I need to configure in the project to get this to work? Help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I have the add the Get verb to the request dto like this:

```
[Route("/test/{id}", "Delete,Get")]
public class TestRequest {
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Now the **Delete** method will be called when simulated via the **Get** request via the **X-HTTP-Method-Override**

```
public class TestService : Service {

    public object Delete(TestRequest request){
        return request.id;
    }
}
```